# Is there a way to add custom onclick icon

Tags: wordpress

I would just like to ask is there a way to add a custom onclick icon on Woocommerce bakcend order list under previous orders column or a custom column would d that will allow the admin can click a flag icon that will turns red when click to determine that the order has a problem.

Please see attached screenshot. https://prnt.sc/m41oad

Thanks,
JM